# JQuery no definido (JQuery is not defined)

Tags: jquery

Ahí dejo el código, ya explote un par de veces y no entiendo por qué no funciona, antes marcaba un error en el if así que lo deje comentado, luego de eso apareció este error de JQuery quizás sea por eso

```
JQuery(document).on('submit', '#lg', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

JQuery.ajax({
 url: 'php/login.php',
 type: 'POST',
 dataType: 'json',
 data: $(this).serialize(),
 /*beforeSend: function(){
    $('.env').val('Validando...');
 }*/
})
.done(function(respuesta){
    console.log(respuesta);
    /*if(|respuesta.error){
        alert("al fin ctm!!!!");
    }else{
        $('.error').slideDown('slow');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.error').slideUp('slow');
        },3000);
        $('.env').val('Iniciar');
    }*/
})
.fail(function(resp){
  console.log(resp.responseText);  
})
.always(function(){
    console.log("complete");
});
});
```

Aquí dejo el código HTML y el de PHP

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilosacademia.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="error">
    <span>asdgasdgasiujdgasijudgsuidgsijuagsduasgdiuaj</span>
</div>

<div class="container">
   <div class="container-fluid">
           <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="text-center">Iniciar Sesión</h3>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal" id="lg" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="user" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Usuario</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user" placeholder="Usuario">
        </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pass" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Contraseña</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pass" placeholder="Contraseña">
            </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                              <input type="checkbox"> Recuerdame
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                      <button type="submit" class="env btn btn-default">Ingresar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
        <p class="text-center">¿No estas registrado?</p> <a href="registrarse.php">¡Registrate!</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
   </div>    
</div>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/login.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
    
    </body>
</html>
```

```
    <?php

require 'conexion.php';

$usuarios = $mysqli -> query("SELECT Nombre, Tipo_usuario 
                             FROM usuarios
                             WHERE Nombre = '".$_POST['user']."' AND Pass = '".$_POST['pass']."'");

if($usuarios -> num_rows == 1):
    $datos =  $usuarios->fetch_assoc();
    echo json_encode(array('error' => false, 'tipo' => $datos['Tipo_usuario']));    
else:    
    echo json_encode(array('error' => true));
endif;

$mysqli->close();


?>
```

Comment: Normalmente es `jQuery` pero lo más común es usar el literal `$` Y como siempre la pregunta típica, ¿Importaste jQuery?

Comment: Donde lo importaste a jQuery?

Comment: Esto parece un fallo tipográfico.

Comment: Usa mejor el $ en lugar del JQuery, tiene mejor compatibilidad.

Comment: @Bitito en el archivo html al final del todo esta importado

Comment: ¿Podes agregar esa línea de código?

Comment: Los scripts colocalos en el head como el css.

Comment: ¿Cuál era el error?

Comment: @Lithorell los scripts no deben ir en el header porque podrían crear una mala experiencia de usuario ya que el navegador debe descargarlos y ejecutarlos antes de continuar procesando el resto de la página, entonces el usuario vería una página en blanco o sin estilos mientras se procesan los script. Más info sobre esto en [Google Dev](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS).

Comment: Como nota no relacionada con tu pregunta, pero sí con tu código: es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL y no debería usarse en entornos de producción. Deberías usar sentencias preparadas en lugar de generar sentencias SQL concatenando cadenas y sin sanear las entradas de usuario.

Answer (score 1):

Creería a simple vista que es `jQuery` con la J en minúscula, a menos que hayas hecho el "mapeo" a esa palabra.

Además no sabemos como estás definiendo a jQuery, normalmente deberías incluir algo así:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Enviare los otros dos códigos que trabajan con el Script,

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto, ponle a tu `boton`, a tu `input` de `usuario` y de `contraseña` en el que mandas los datos, un `id` esto para realizar busqueda con `JQUERY`

Ejemplo: (Esto sería agregarle solamente los id a tus elementos en tu `HTML`)

```html
 <input id="usuario" type="text" class="form-control" name="user" placeholder="Usuario">
<input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="pass" placeholder="Contraseña">
<button id="enviar" type="submit" class="env btn btn-default">Ingresar</button>
```

Luego en tu documento JQUERY pon este código.

```js
$(document).ready(function()){
 event.preventDefault();
 var1 = $('#usuario').val(); //guardamos que tecleaste en el input de usuario
 var2 = $('#password').val(); //lo mismo que el anterior
 $('#enviar').click(function(event) {//en el evento click del boton lo enviamos al servidor para la peticion ajax
  $.ajax({
   url: 'php/login.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data: {var1, var2}, //son las variables que guardamos
   beforeSend:function(){
    console.log("Se esta procesando tu peticion");
   }
  })
  .done(function(data) {
   console.log("data");      
  })
  .fail(function() {
   console.log("error");
  })
  .always(function() {
   console.log("complete");
  });
 });

});
```

Obviamente en tu `HTML` tienes que tener referenciado tu archivo `JS`

Algo asi:

```html
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> <!--Utilizar libreria JQUERY-->
<script src="js/codigo.js"></script> <!--TODO lo que utilize JQUERY deberá ser referenciado
```

Salúdos.